# nodejs a function is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can't figure out why I have the error "x is not a function".

```
for (var i = 0; i < bdds.length; i++) {
 var callback = function(rows){
   console.log("rows: "+rows);
 };
 var sql1 = "SELECT host_name, instance_name FROM v$instance";
 console.log(bdds[i].reqOracle);//=> [function]
 bdds[i].reqOracle(sql1,callback);//=> Error reqOracle is not a function
 bdds[i].getOracleConnection(bdds[i], function(){//=> no error
  [...]
 });
}
```

My object Bdd:

```
var tcpp = require('tcp-ping');
var async = require('async');
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var sqlListDAO = require('./sqlListDAO');

function Bdd(name, ip, login, password, port, sid, type, wallet, version){...}

Bdd.prototype.getOracleConnection = function(bdd, callback){...}

Bdd.prototype.reqOracle = function(sql, callback){...}
```

getOracleConnection() can be executed without eny error but reqOracle (a function in the same object) can't.

Comment: What does `console.log(typeof bdds[i].reqOracle);` say? I'm guessing something in mangling it into a string. You really should provide a real [MCVE].

Comment: I've fix my issue, with typeof i was able to see more clearly what was going on thx =)